# Collapsable toggle not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have searched for solutions and failed. I apologize in advance for such a novice question. The toggle when clicked does not expand into menu items. I have this working on the "home" page but cannot get it to do so on the linked pages. The code is nearly identical as on the functioning toggle, are the java scripts in the body at the end of the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-3">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="../Lark_home_page2.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="../Lark_User_Objects.zip">Download</a></li>
  <li><a href="../Lark_tutorials/Lark_tutorials.html">Tutorials</a></li>
  <li><a href="Lark_resources.html">Resources</a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:lark.spectral.light@gmail.com">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are the linked pages in sub-directories?  You probably have a relative path issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></div>` wrapper:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> <!-- you are missing this line-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="../Lark_home_page2.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../Lark_User_Objects.zip">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../Lark_tutorials/Lark_tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Lark_resources.html">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="mailto:lark.spectral.light@gmail.com">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

  </div><!-- you are missing this line-->
```